# Reaproveitando formulários em php

Tags: php, formulário

Estou trabalhando em um site em PHP em que eu possuo umas 20 páginas diferentes que possuem o mesmo formulário. Atualmente este site possui nas 20 páginas o mesmo código para o formulário (ctrl+c/ctrl+v). Existe uma forma de utilizar o mesmo formulário nessas 20 páginas de uma forma mais simples? Eu não estou acostumado com PHP.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Pode me mostrar um exemplo dentro deste cenário?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que precisa é de criar um ficheiro php (por exemplo `formulario.php`) só com o código do formulário e depois incluí-lo nos 20 ficheiros.

Assim só precisa de alterar o código num só sitio, e nos 20 ficheiros só precisa fazer:

```
<?php include('/formulario.php' ); ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Isto é muito comum em partes do site que são comuns, como cabeçalhos, menus ou footer. Muitas vezes usa-se esta técnica para incluir ficheiros que só têm funções que são uteis e comuns às páginas específicas.

Comment: Essa é melhor solução!